# Python Tkinter resizing window and Canvas issues

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, tkinter, resize

Hi i have this simple code which creates a tkinter window, resizes it and draws a line. **Why this line is being drawn almost in the center when it should start at the top left corner? (See the photo attached)**

```
import tkinter
# window size
window_size = 20 * 20
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(window_size * 2, window_size))
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='red', width=10)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need that canvas would fill the window: (canvas.pack(fill='both'))

The complete code for canvas to take whole window space:

```
canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```